GFPGAN CoreML model isn't working correctly
I tried downloading the GFPGAN CoreML model from hoseins77/gfpgan and TheMurusTeam/coreml-upscaler-gfpgan, but when I used it in my project, the outputted images did not come out right. GFPGAN appears to work fine in general since it works online here, but the CoreML models don't appear to work.
Here's a couple examples:


And here's my code that runs the model. Is there some additional configuration I need to do to make the GFPGAN CoreML model work?
func getPhotoSharpened(_ photo: CGImage) async -> CGImage? {
  guard let vnModel = await getVNModelFromStorage() else { return nil }

  let coreMLRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: vnModel)
  coreMLRequest.imageCropAndScaleOption = .scaleFit

  do {
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: photo, options: [:])
    try handler.perform([coreMLRequest])
  } catch {
    print("Error sharpening photo: \(error)")
  }

  guard
    let results = coreMLRequest.results as? [VNPixelBufferObservation],
    let outputPixelBuffer = results.first?.pixelBuffer
  else {
    print("Unable to get output from model"); return nil
  }

  let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: outputPixelBuffer)
  let desiredAspectRatio = CGFloat(photo.width) / CGFloat(photo.height)
  // cropped function is defined elsewhere.
  let croppedImage = cropped(ciImage, toAspectRatio: desiredAspectRatio)

  let context = CIContext()
  guard let sharpenedImage = context.createCGImage(croppedImage, from: croppedImage.extent) else {
    print("Failed to create sharpened CGImage from CIImage")
    return nil
  }

  return sharpenedImage
}

private func getVNModelFromStorage() async -> VNCoreMLModel? {
  do {
    // gpfganFileUrl is defined elsewhere.
    let mlModel = try await MLModel.load(contentsOf: gpfganFileUrl, configuration: .init())
    return try VNCoreMLModel(for: mlModel)
  } catch {
    print("Unable to load GFPGAN model from file with error: \(error)"); return nil
  }
}


